# Arcpy map algebra from reticulate

Tags: r, arcpy, reticulate

I'm trying to use `arcpy` from R via `reticulate`. For the most part, it works really well. However, I'm running into some issues when trying to do raster algebra. Consider the following code:

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("C:/Python27/ArcGISx6410.2")

arcpy = import("arcpy")
arcpy$CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

arcpy$management$CreateRandomRaster("in_memory", 
  "randrast", "NORMAL 3.0", "0 0 500 500", 50)

randrast = arcpy$sa$Raster("in_memory/randrast")

doublerast = randrast + randrast
```

> Error in randrast + randrast : non-numeric argument to binary operator

It seems that even though `reticulate` recognizes that the rasters are Python objects (`"python.builtin.Raster" "python.builtin.object"`), it doesn't know to use Python's `+` operator rather than R's. I tried importing `arcpy` with `convert = FALSE` but the error is the same.

I can get around this by defining Python functions to mimic the basic arithmetic operators.

```
tmp = tempfile(fileext = ".py")
cat("def add(x, y):\n  return x + y\n", file = tmp)

source_python(tmp)

doublerast = add(randrast, randrast)
```

But obviously this is gets pretty cumbersome for more complex statements.

Does anyone know of a way to force `reticulate` to use Python's arithmetic operators for Python objects, rather than R's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to define my own operators for Python objects using the `operator` module:

```
`%py+%` = function(e1, e2) {
  op = import("operator")
  op$add(e1, e2)
}

doublerast = randrast %py+% randrast
```

Or, alternatively, use S3 classes to overload the arithmetic operators (as is done for [TensorFlow](https://github.com/rstudio/tensorflow/blob/master/R/generics.R#L78)) to support `python.builtin.object`, e.g.

```
`+.python.builtin.object` = function(e1, e2) {
  op = import("operator")
  op$add(e1, e2)
}
```

But I worry that order of operations might not function as expected.